# XOR-ing and Summing Two Black and White Images

Tags: python, image, xor

Starting with two images `im1` and `im2` created with the PIL module, we have the corresponding black and white images,

```
bw_im1 = im1.convert('1')
```

and

```
bw_im2 = im2.convert('1')
```

Each pixel of `bw_im2` and `bw_im2` is either 0 or 256.

Suppose both `bw_im2` and `bw_im2` have the same size.

> How do you XOR all the corresponding entries and then sum them
>   up?

**My Work**

I wrote the following *stub / proof of concept* Python program, but worried that using the code (unpacking/translating over) would be complicated. There might be a more direct and efficient way to process the pixels in the two images.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.zeros((2, 3))
M[0,2] = 255
M[1,0] = 255
M[1,1] = 255    
print(M)

N = np.zeros((2, 3))
N = np.zeros((2, 3))
N[0,2] = 255
N[1,1] = 255  
N[1,2] = 255
print(N)

list_M = list(M)
list_N = list(N)
xor_signal = 0
for row in range(0, len(list_M)):
    for col in range(0,len(list_M[row])):
        xor_signal = xor_signal + int(bool(list_M[row][col]) !=  bool(list_N[row][col]))

print(xor_signal)
```

OUTPUT

```
[[  0.   0. 255.]
 [255. 255.   0.]]
[[  0.   0. 255.]
 [  0. 255. 255.]]
2
```

Comment: Huh? Neither of the 2 images you mention, nor PIL, appear in your code?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Update under MyWork to make it more clear - the program is a 'proof of concept'. Are you saying that the best idea is to write a full fledged program that can 'plug into it'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use PIL's **ImageChops** like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

# Open images
im1 = Image.open("im1.png")
im2 = Image.open("im2.png")

result = ImageChops.logical_xor(im1,im2)
result.save('result.png')
```

So, if you start with these two:

[image]

[image]

The result will be:

[image]

Of course, if you are a physicist, you can write that like this ;-)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from PIL import Image, ImageChops 
ImageChops.logical_xor(Image.open("im1.png"), Image.open("im2.png")).save('result.png')
```

---

Or you can use Numpy's XOR like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open images
im1 = Image.open("im1.png")
im2 = Image.open("im2.png")

# Make into Numpy arrays
im1np = np.array(im1)*255
im2np = np.array(im2)*255

# XOR with Numpy
result = np.bitwise_xor(im1np, im2np).astype(np.uint8)

# Convert back to PIL image and save
Image.fromarray(result).save('result.png')
```

You can sum the pixels by adding this at the end:

```
print('Sum: {}'.format(np.sum(result)))
```

---

Or you can not bother writing any Python and just type the following **ImageMagick** command into your Terminal:

```
magick im1.png im2.png -evaluate-sequence xor result.png
```

If you are using v6, or older, use the following instead:

```
convert im1.png im2.png -evaluate-sequence xor result.png
```

Comment: Can you (directly) sum the contents of result: `result = ImageChops.logical_xor(im1,im2)`? Tried `sum(result)` but got `TypeError: 'Image' object is not iterable` .

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that bit and am not at a computer at the minute. You can make a Numpy array of the result and sum that... something like `np.sum(np.array(result))`

Comment: If the images are not black and white, we should convert them, otherwise we get the error "ValueError: image has wrong mode": im1 = Image.open("im1.png").convert('1')

Comment: How to do this on curved images that have anti-aliasing effects on them? Should I create the mask images with transparent background instead of black - and the XOR operation take care of anti-aliased pixels automatically?